# What is the main difference between user define class and String class

Tags: c#

I have one **student** class which has properties,methods and variables which any class in object orientation concept contains. When I gone through metadata of **String** class in dot net, It also contains properties,methods,variables. So when we assign value to the String we does this normally :

```
String s = "Code Project"; // No compile error (1st line)

String test = new String(); // Compile error  (2rd line)
```

Error in 2nd line:

> 'string' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

but as I know every class in dot net should have **at least one constructor**

Secondly,

If String class contains properties, methods, variables. Then how the 1st line code works.
and the if same thing I have tried to do with my Student class it shows me compile error.

```
Student s= "Code Project"; // Compile error  (3rd line)
```

Is there any **extra things** they did with the predefined classes? 
which we cannot do in user define classes.

Can I make a another String class similar to this?

Comment: `but as I know every class in dot net should have at least one constructor` what? Where did you hear that? Lots of classes only have one constructor.

Comment: Every class in .NET has at least one constructor, that statement is correct. But your assumption seems to be that there will be always be a parameterless constructor, which is not true. A parameterless constructor is only added to a class, when that class doesn't define any constructors.

Comment: @Frank no it isn't: `static class Foo {}` has no constructors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `String` class does not have a parameterless constructor so `String test = new String()` does not compile as you have discovered. You can use one of the other [string constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.string(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a string. However, the normal way to create a string is to use a string literal, e.g. `String s = "Code Project"` but this is only possible because the `String` type gets special treatment by the compiler.

For your own types you can create an [implicit user-defined type conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx). Here is an example:

```
class Student {

  public Student(String name) {
    if (name == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
    Name = name;
  }

  public static implicit operator Student(String name) {
    return new Student(name);
  }

  public String Name { get; private set; }

}
```

This code will allow you to create the following assignment:

```
Student student = "Code Project";
```

This will invoke the implicit operator and create a new `Student` with `Name = "Code Project"`.

Using implicit operators can be useful but also confusing because the conversion is implicit and without looking at the source code for `Student` you may have a hard time understanding what is going on. An alternative is creating an [explicit user-defined type conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx):

```
public static explicit operator Student(String name) {
  return new Student(name);
}
```

Here you will have to use a cast to invoke the operator making it more explicit what is going on:

```
Student student = (Student) "Code Project";
```

or even

```
var student = (Student) "Code Project";
```

Answer (score 3):

`string` is special in the sense that it can be constructed by assigning it a literal character-sequence expression. This is a special feature of the language.

Yes, every class has at least 1 constructor. If no constructors are user-defined, there is a parameterless one added behind the scenes.

[`string` has 8 constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) but none of them are parameterless.

You can't construct your own class by assigning it a character-sequence expression.

Comment: I think the OP is confused why I can do `var str = ""` but I can't do `var myClass = SomeLiteralHere`. I think the clarification point is that `String/string` have language-level support (see `using/IDisposable`)

Comment: I know that class has at least one constructor if we don't explicitly define any constructor (parameter or parameter less) than compiler create default for us. BUT String class not compile this statement: String s=new String(); It shows "'string' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments"

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel Thanks for this line "You can't construct your own class by assigning it a character-sequence expression"

Comment: @Suraj: re-read my third remark. The parameterless constructor is not defined and others are; ergo: it is not available. Dan: yeah, that's what I meant with my first remark. I'll make it clearer.

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel Its my mistake. I forgot that if class has  parameterized constructor than default not created by compiler. If we want to use default than we have to declare it explicitly.Thanks a lot. :)